# Child Fragment is not animated on EnterTransition

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions

After changing to the Android Navigation Component I encountered some problems with migrating my Activity Transitions to the corresponding Fragment Transitions.

Specifically, it appears that the EnterTransition of a Fragment doesn't apply to it's Child Fragments.

I've set up a test activity that contains an OuterTestFragment, which in turn consists of a TextView and another fragment, InnerTestFragment. 
A button in the activity then replaces the OuterTestFragment with a new OuterTestFragment to see if the contents transition smoothly.

Here are the relevant classes:

Activity:

```
public class PlaygroundActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    static {
        strings.add("sgdgdgsdfggggggggsdgsdfgsd\nsdsdgsdfgds\ndfgsd\nsdsdgsdfgds\ndfgsd");
        strings.add("sgdgdgsdfgggg\nggggsndfgsd\nsdsdgsdfgds\ndfgsd");
        strings.add("sgdgsd\nsdsdgsdfgds\ndfgsd");
        strings.add("sgdgdgsdfggfgds\ndfgsd");
        strings.add("sgdgdgsdfggggggggsdg");
    }

    int count = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_playground);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainerOuter, OuterTestFragment.getInstance("This is an inner text", "Outer text!"))
                .commit();
    }

    public void replace(View v) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                .addToBackStack("replaced")
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainerOuter, InnerTestFragment.getInstance(count++ >= 4 ? "Default" : strings.get(count)))
                .commit();
    }
}
```

OuterTestFragment:

```
public class OuterTestFragment extends TransitionedFragment {

    private static final String ARG_OUTER_TEXT = "OuterTestFragment:outerText";
    private static final String ARG_INNER_TEXT = "OuterTestFragment:innerText";

    private String innerText;
    private String outerText;

    public static OuterTestFragment getInstance(String inner, String outer) {
        OuterTestFragment outerFragment = new OuterTestFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_OUTER_TEXT, outer);
        args.putString(ARG_INNER_TEXT, inner);
        outerFragment.setArguments(args);
        return outerFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        innerText = getArguments().getString(ARG_INNER_TEXT);
        outerText = getArguments().getString(ARG_OUTER_TEXT);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment_outer, container, false);
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textOuter)).setText(outerText);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, InnerTestFragment.getInstance(innerText))
                .commit();

        return layout;
    }
}
```

TransitionedFragment:

```
public abstract class TransitionedFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TransitionInflater inflater = TransitionInflater.from(getContext());
        setEnterTransition(inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.default_transition));
        setReenterTransition(inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.default_transition));
        setSharedElementEnterTransition(inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.scaled_img_clip_transition));
    }
}
```

Inner Test Fragment:

```
public class InnerTestFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_TEXT = "InnerTestFragment:text";

    private String text;

    public static InnerTestFragment getInstance(String text) {
        InnerTestFragment frgmt = new InnerTestFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_TEXT, text);
        frgmt.setArguments(args);
        return frgmt;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        text = getArguments().getString(ARG_TEXT);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment_inner, container, false);
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(text);
        return layout;
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, as the Transition API drives me nuts....

Answer (score 0):

You may show transitions with the setEnterTransition method.

```
Fragment fragment = InnerTestFragment.getInstance(innerText);
Fade enterFade = new Fade(); //can be any transition, SlideTransition or Inflated Transitions
enterFade.setDuration(300); //Duration of transition in ms

fragment.setEnterTransition(enterFade);

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
            .commit();
```

Comment: I don't want to apply a transition to the InnerFragment. The changing OuterFragments should be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a background color to the child fragment...